# How to implement this EigenVector Python Code in Java

Tags: java, eigenvalue, markov-chains

I have found the right result of an Algorithm. Can I implement this code in Java?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import eig 
transition_mat = np.matrix([
    [0.8,  0.15,0.05 ],\
    [0.075,0.85,0.075],\
    [0.05, 0.15,0.8  ]])

S, U = eig(transition_mat.T)
stationary = np.array(U[:np.where(np.abs(S - 1.) < 1e-8)[0][0]].flat)
print stationary
print np.sum(stationary)
stationary = stationary / np.sum(stationary)

print stationary
```

I have implemented this code in Java but the result is wrong

```
Matrix A = new Matrix(transition);
        A = A.transpose();
        Matrix x = new Matrix(N, 1, 1.0 / N); // initial guess for eigenvector
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            x = A.times(x);
            x = x.times(1.0 / x.norm1());       // rescale
        }
        
        // compute by finding eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue = 1
        EigenvalueDecomposition eig = new EigenvalueDecomposition(A);
        Matrix V = eig.getV();
        double[] real = eig.getRealEigenvalues();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(real[i] - 1.0) < 1E-8) {
                x = V.getMatrix(0, N-1, i, i);
                x = x.times(1.0 / x.norm1());
                System.out.println("Stationary distribution using eigenvector:");
                x.print(9, 6);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is your current/expected result? (edit your question to add it)

Comment: The Result is Null

Comment: If I remove             if (Math.abs(real[i] - 1.0) < 1E-8) {
}
result showed but it's wrong result

Comment: In Java -0.040173, -0.147368, 0.812459
In Python -0.40824829 -0.81649658 -0.40824829

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look the code *seems* correct, provided that

1. your matrix `transition` is the same as in the python example. From your result I assume
2. the method `Matrix.times` does a vector multiplication and not a entry-wise multiplication
3. the number of 50 iterations should be enough for this example. In cases where your 2nd eigenvalue is also close to one this number will be **much** larger
4. the function `EigenvalueDecomposition.getV` returns the eigenvectors in the orientation you expect (row / column)

Note that a valid *transition matrix* (the matrix of jumping probabilities) has row or column sum of 1 (a matter of definition) since the chances of staying or switching must be 100%. This implies the existance of an eigenvectors of one. From your use of initial transpose of the matrix, I assume you need row-sum of one.

Since you seem to not have an eigenvalue of 1, the most logical error is a typo in your matrix.